# String replace with multiple occurrences

Tags: php, string, replace

I have the following string

```
Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re:
```

What I want is the end result of mutating this string is:

```
Re:
```

So what I am looking for is a way to detect multiple `Re:` (with a space in between) and change it to just one `Re:`.

If I had any idea how to accomplish this I'd post some code but no real clue how to do this in `php`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
<?php
$s = "Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Prueba";
$s = preg_replace("/(Re: ?){2,}/i", "Re: ", $s);
var_dump($s); // Re: Prueba
```

Explanation:

```
(Re: ?) is just Re: and an optional space between them.
{2,}    means 2 or more times (if it's just one, why replace it)
i       so it's case insensitive
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/fgtAe)